# vertically align p tag next to image

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a p tag i would like vertically aligned next to an image. The problem I am having is that only the first line of text is vertically aligned. How do 
i get the text in the p tag to wrap next to the image and maintain vertical alignment?

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="blog">
    <div class="post">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/a3b5c4/000000.jpg&text=example+of+donation+feed">
      <p>“Once someone dreams a dream, it can't just drop out of existence. But if the dreamer can't remember it, what becomes of it? It lives on in Fantastica, deep under earth. There are forgotten dreams stored in many layers. The deeper one digs, the closer they are. All Fantastica rests on a foundation of forgotten dreams.”</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
<style>
.blog img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.blog p {
  display: inline;
}
</style>
```

---

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`display: flex;` on the parent and `align-items: center` to center the contents vertically.

```css
.post {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="blog">
    <div class="post">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/a3b5c4/000000.jpg&text=example+of+donation+feed">
      <p>“Once someone dreams a dream, it can't just drop out of existence. But if the dreamer can't remember it, what becomes of it? It lives on in Fantastica, deep under earth. There are forgotten dreams stored in many layers. The deeper one digs, the closer they are. All Fantastica rests on a foundation of forgotten dreams.”</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This did it! Thanks, Michael!

Comment: @J.M.Habibi awesome! np :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use grid system though it may detour.

```
.parent {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
} 

img { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; }
p { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; }
```

in my case, it automatically aligned vertically.

For mor information. You can visit [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Answer (score 0):

CSS code shoulde be:

```
.blog img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.blog p {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirement, you want the whole paragraph adjacent to your image?

The simplest solution is to use CSS `table` properties. Note that this does *not* mean to use tables. Rather it simply *displays* elements as such.

Here is some sample CSS

```
div.blog {
    display: table;
}
div.blog>img {
    display: table-cell;
}
div.blog>p {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

The `display:table` in the first property is not strictly necessarily, but the default would be `display:table-row`, which gives you less control over sizing.